# Use parameters in function after interrupt signal

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possisble in bash script to use parameters in a function, which is called after interrupt signal? Here's my code:

```
    inCaseOfInterrupt ()
    {
        while [ $# -gt 0 ]
        do
                echo "$1"
                shift
        done
        exit 0
    }
```

And in the other part of my script I have:

```
trap inCaseOfInterrupt 2
```

But it doesn't recognize my parameters. How can I use parameters in a function after script gets interrupt signal?

Answer (score 0):

```
trap 'inCaseOfInterrupt 2' 2
```

Or, with a signal name:

```
trap 'inCaseOfInterrupt 2' INT
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I pass parameters: "test1 test2 test3", I get "2" on the output instead of "test1 test2 test3", which I expected.

Comment: Pass parameters how?

Comment: When I run my script in Bash shell:
./myScript test1 test2 test3